# This bug appeared in my java program for what appears to be no reason

Tags: java, image, sprite

For some reason, when my sprite hits the edge on the left it does not rebound. The program was working perfectly, but then I changed something that really should have no effect on it at all and it stopped working.

```
//Sprite class

public class Sprite {
private String sprite = "sprite-adult.fw.png";

private int speed;
private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;

public Sprite() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(sprite));
    image = ii.getImage();

            speed=6;
            dx=speed;
            dy=speed;

    x = 40;
    y = 60;
}
public void move() {
    toggleRebound();

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
public void toggleRebound() {
    if(x == 1366) 
        dx = negate(dx);

    if(y == 768) 
        dy = negate(dy);

    if(x == 0) 
        dx = negate(dx);

    if(y == 0) 
        dy = negate(dy);    
}
public int negate(int x) {
    return x*-1;
}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
}


//SType class

public class SType extends JFrame{
public SType() {
    add(new Board());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1366,768);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("S - Type");
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SType();
}
}

//Board class

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private Sprite sprite;
private Timer timer;

public Board() {
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(new Color(39,124,36));
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    sprite = new Sprite();

    timer = new Timer(5,this);
    timer.start();
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Random rand = new Random(5398);
    for(int x=0;x<1000;x++) {
        g.setColor(new Color(22,98,19));
        g.drawOval(rand.nextInt(1368), rand.nextInt(768), 1, 20);
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(),sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),this);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    sprite.move();
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: When you say "it does not rebound", can you be clearer? Does it just sit there? Does the code throw an exception?  Does it still rebound off the bottom?  Or the right or top?  Did it ever?

Comment: it goes right through the "wall" as if there was nothing there

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck.  I'm editing my answer a little more to make it more useful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two lessons to learn here**

**First, the real problem you're having is that you're checking for rebound by exact equality** with zero (or your hardcoded left/top sizes).  This means that if you move more than one pixel at a time (as you are, in the code above), you can miss the border and sail through it.

Generally speaking, it's often a good practice to check limits with lessthan-equals, especially when there's a possiblity of "moving" more than one at a time.

For example, if you wanted to write an array class, you wouldn't do your bounds checking with `((idx == 0) or (idx == length))`.  You'd check for `((idx <= 0) or (idx >= length))`, instead.

Same thing with sprite position.

**Second, it's always useful to check your assumptions, especially when your expectations are violated**.  In this case, you were sure that one very simple change had broken your program.

But that wasn't true. It couldn't have been true.  Under no circumstances is this:

```
private int dx = 6;
private int dy = 6;
```

different from this:

```
private int speed = 6
private int dx = speed;
private int dy = speed;
```

So something else changed between your two measurement points (working, non-working).  It's entirely possible that this additional change was masked from you somehow - perhaps by a compile error, or maybe you were just looking at some other aspect of the program, and not letting it bounce.  But whatever the reason, something else changed.

In this particular case, you probably also changed either your start point or the value of your speed.

But whatever the cause, when you hit an impossible point, you must go back and recheck your assumptions.

But regardless, that's the problem: your sprite is "moving" too fast for your current rebound to catch it.   Change to a less-than-equals test, would be my recommendation.

You are incorrect.   Making that change, and only that change, did not cause the change in behavior you report.

Most likely, you actually made more than one change, but only tested the rebound behavior after this point.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the bug appeared after I made that change. I ran the program and it was fine. I made the change and only that change and it did not work.

Comment: What you're trying to say cannot be true.  I'm happy to help you, but you will have to go at it correctly, and thinking that the change you describe is _all_ that happened will keep you from finding the truth.

Comment: I added the other two classes. I am fairly certain nothing else was changed. I looked through it a couple of times and could not find the problem.

Comment: Simple test: revert your change, recompile, and observe the behavior.  Once you see that reverting those lines and only those lines does not restore correct behavior, we can proceed.

Comment: I tried that. Nothing happened. I also undid everything I added well past when the bug appeared and it still did not fix itself.

Answer (score 2):

The first answerer is correct, this should not affect anything.  Though it isn't really relevant in this example, it's good form to initialize private instance variables in the constructor rather than with their declarations.

```
private int speed;
private int dx;
private int dy;

public Sprite()
{
    speed=6;
    dx=speed;
    dy=speed;
}
```